# tableofcontents in beamer

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, sectioning

I need to do tableofcontents ,where the was only one section on frame,other section on next frame ,but only one section at slide, like this

[image]

not like this

[image]

and not like this

[image]

How can I do it ,help me ,please.
MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\begin{document}
\frame{\tableofcontents} 
\section{ap1}
\subsection{ap1.1}
\subsection{ap1.2}
\subsection{ap1.3}
 \begin{frame}



    \end{frame}
\section{ap2}
\subsection{ap2.1}
\subsection{ap2.2}
\subsection{ap2.3}
\begin{frame}



\end{frame}
\section{ap3}
\subsection{ap3.1}
\subsection{ap3.2}
\subsection{ap3.3}
\begin{frame}



\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}

    \foreach \i in {1,...,3}{
       \frame{
         \tableofcontents[
          sections=\i] }
                            }

 \section{ap1}
    \subsection{ap1.1}
    \subsection{ap1.2}
    \subsection{ap1.3}

 \section{ap2}
     \subsection{ap2.1}
     \subsection{ap2.2}
     \subsection{ap2.3}

 \section{ap3}
    \subsection{ap3.1}
    \subsection{ap3.2}
    \subsection{ap3.3}

\begin{frame}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok , but where is second section ? I need that it will be at diffrent frames , only one section at frame , but all section in presentation

Comment: But if i have frames before another section , I have parts of tableofcontents in another parts of presentation , how can i fix it ?

Comment: I edit MWE ,when I use your method ,I have slides  of presentation in tableofcontents

Comment: ok, i edit the text

Comment: When I use your code in my MWE , i have empty slide between first and second section in table-of-contents , but I need that table-of-contents continuous and will be before all presentation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93747/discussion-between-hafid-boukhoulda-and-re1nex).

Comment: Yes ,it is that i need ,Thank you !